# Kafka Error while sending messages to the topic

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming

I am new to kafka, When I am trying to send messages to the topic I am getting below error.
Can someone help me with this?

> [2018-09-23 13:37:56,613] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Comment: `Broker may not be available`... Lots of reasons for this. Please verify that Kafka is actually running at the list of addresses you have in your code

Comment: Thanks for the response, Yes Kafka broker is running. Checked everything even in Kafka logs also didn't find anything wrong.

Comment: Running where? Which IP or hostname did you provide to connect to it?

Comment: I installed Kafka in google cloud as a single node, so I gave the same IP for the Kafka broker and tried to send messages from Kafka producer.

Comment: Did you open the Kafka port from Google to your network? Did you use the external IP address?

Comment: Yes, I opened all the ports, I tried to use both external and internal IP's but still it's failing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your `server.properties` file and the addresses you're trying to connect to

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Kafka in a cloud service, then you need to configure the listeners appropriately. Almost certainly your client is connecting to the broker, but in the metadata returned by the broker getting an *interal IP* for the cloud network, which your external client cannot access.

This article explains it all, and the solution: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/